# Can I volunteer while in America?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens, volunteering

So I'm staying in America for 12 weeks soon and was wondering if I can do volunteer work while there?

I'm visiting on an ESTA and am a UK Citizen, if that helps!